# Nested forEach not finding item

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can anyone tell me why this nested for loop does not match on 'Greetings', which is in the JSON it is passed (on the "second level").

I have a sample [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-on2pzd?file=index.ts), see the console.

```typescript
    menuItems.forEach((firstLevel) => {
      if (firstLevel.items) {
        firstLevel.items.forEach((secondLevel) => {
          if (secondLevel.items) {
            secondLevel.items.forEach((thirdLevel) => {
              console.log('L3 processing ' + thirdLevel.label);
            });
            console.log('L2 processing ' + secondLevel.label);
    
            if (secondLevel.label === 'Greetings') {
              console.log('Found Greetings');
            }
          }
        });
      }
      console.log('L1 processing ' + firstLevel.label);
    });
```

Comment: Please add the "JSON" in the question. We should not have to follow a link to find all relevant information. NB: the linked page has no JSON, but a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: because it does not have items..... `{ label: 'Greetings', routerLink: '/features/greeting-manager' },` is not going to go into the `if (secondLevel.items) {` basic logic flaw....

Comment: Quite a lot of JS devs block sites with JS funnily enough, so I couldn't even access the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your secondLevel iteration is asking for any "secondLevel" that has an items array, and the "Greetings" one does not have any "items" property